# React async method setState variable not being set in time

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, solidity, ipfs

I'm trying to run 3 methods after each other when a user clicks a button

Steps:

1: Push a file to IPFS, get the link back and assign it to a state variable

2: Add that link (from that var) to blockchain smart contract

3: Add an entry to the firebase database

The problem is that that IPFS link is null when I try to pass it to my smart contract, however after the method runs I can see the link print to console.
So I'm guessing it is not being set in time for the next method to see the variable.

IPFS Method:

```
pushToIPFS = async(e) => {
      //  e.preventDefault()
        await ipfs.add(this.state.buffer, (err, ipfsHash) => {
            console.log(err, ipfsHash)
            //this.setState({IPFSlink : ipfsHash[0].hash})
            console.log(ipfsHash[0].hash)
            return ipfsHash[0].hash
        })
    }
```

Blockchain method:

```
addToBlockchain = async(e) => {
        //create a new key for our student
        var key = this.state.StudentNumber + this.state.account[0]
        key = parseInt(hash(key), 10)
        this.setState({idForBlockchain: key})
        console.log(key)

        //get todays date
        let newDate = new Date()
        newDate = newDate.getTime()
        var _ipfsLink = this.state.IPFSlink
        var _account = this.state.account[0]
        console.log(_ipfsLink)
        console.log(this.state.IPFSlink)
        await storehash.methods.sendDocument(_ipfsLink, newDate, 


    }
```

Firebase method:

```
createStudent = async(e) => {
        //get student details from state variables & current user uid
        var _uid = this.state.uid
        var _studentName = this.state.StudentName
        var _studentNumber = this.state.StudentNumber
        var _courseCode = this.state.CourseCode
        var _courseName = this.state.CourseName
        var _idForBlockchain = this.state.idForBlockchain

        // database.ref.students.uid.studentNumber 
        const db = firebase.database()
        db.ref().child("students").child(_uid).child(_studentNumber).set(
            {   studentName: _studentName,
                courseCode: _courseCode,
                courseName: _courseName,
                blockchainKey: _idForBlockchain 
            }
        );

        alert("Student added")

    }
```

The method that triggers when the button is clicked:

```
AddMyStuff = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        await this.pushToIPFS()
        await this.addToBlockchain()
        await this.createStudent()
    }
```

This is the error returned, so what I assume is the await and setState are causing issues and the variable I need is not being set.

> Unhandled Rejection (Error): invalid string value (arg="_ipfsLocation", coderType="string", value=null, version=4.0.27)

Does anyone know how this can be solved?

Comment: `ipfs.add` is taking a callback, it's not returning a promise. there's nothing to `await`

Comment: Sorry, I'm kinda new to this. So is the await not needed since there is no promise?

Comment: If you want to do sth after setState has run just give it a callback as second parameter.

Comment: Give which method a callback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can convert your pushToIPFS to be a promise instead of a callback, and just resolve it when the callback is fired.

```
pushToIPFS = (e) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          ipfs.add(this.state.buffer, (err, ipfsHash) => {
            resolve(ipfsHash[0].hash);
        })
    });
}
```

And since its a promise you can use `async/await`.

```
AddMyStuff = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        const ipfsHash = await this.pushToIPFS();
        //you have your ipfsHash defined, you can pass it to your other methods
    }
```